# "ORA-01109: database not open" when trying to open a database

Tags: oracle, oracle-18c

Everything I can find about ORA-01109 says "run `alter pluggable database XXX open;`", but I'm getting ORA-01109 when running that command!

`select name, open_mode from v$containers;`

```
NAME         OPEN_MODE 
------------ ----------
CDB$ROOT     MOUNTED   
PDB$SEED     MOUNTED   
XEPDB1       MOUNTED
```

`alter pluggable database cdb$root open;`

```
Error starting at line : 2 in command -
alter pluggable database cdb$root open
Error report -
ORA-01109: database not open
01109. 00000 -  "database not open"
*Cause:    A command was attempted that requires the database to be open.
*Action:   Open the database and try the command again
```

Comment: You using RAC? If so try adding ` instances=all` to your alter statement.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you open the root container (which is not a pluggable database). Simply use:

`alter database open;`

Comment: Thanks! Now it's complaining about a missing data file that I don't know why it wants...

Comment: Its already opened but still getting the same error while making connection in Oracle SQL Developer software. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70706962/oracle-db-service-is-already-opened-but-still-getting-database-not-open-error